# How to calculate a Label Point for a (multi)polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry

ESRI software has a concept of a 'label point' for a (multi)polygon. It is like the centroid, except it is guaranteed to be within the (multi)polygon. Like for a U-shaped polygon, the label point is somewhere in the bottom of the U. See the ArcGIS REST API [Reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/labelpoints.html) on the subject.

I'd like to know a reference, English description, or pseudocode for how something like this is calculated for a polygon or multipolygon.

I get the vibe from results in ArcGIS that the label point is somewhere on the the medial axis transform (skeleton). But not just in its middle, because a big bulge at one end of a polygon will pull the label point into it. So it has a 'center of mass' aspect.

I haven't found an equivalent function in PostGIS (there is [ST_PointOnSurface](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_PointOnSurface.html), but that is not quite the same thing). Nor have I found something in QGIS, but maybe I'm not looking for the right non-ESRI terminology.

This duplicates [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/algorithm-for-finding-irrregular-polygon-centroid-label-point) question, but that one didn't get any high-rated non-hacky answers so I thought I'd ask again. Forgive me if it isn't the done thing.

Comment: Just based on empirical evaluation, the label point of a single-part polygon is the midpoint of the largest horizontal transect at ~1/4, ~1/2, and ~3/4 of the BND. Multi-part might be on the largest part, or the first part; I haven't tested that. Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/189580/edit) this question to specify the software for which you want this answer, since right now it's three different questions (ArcGIS, PostGIS, and QGIS).

Comment: See @whuber answer in the post you hyperlinked. It mentions negative buffer = pseudocode

Comment: Negative buffer is an extremely expensive way to calculate a label point.  Horizontal or diagonal transects use the intersection of three or two lines across the figure, while negative buffers are computationally expensive (trig functions) and iterative.

Comment: @Vince It seems he means centre of largest inscribed circle (big bulge), not just some point inside. Yes buffer is slow but it is a buil-in function, so logic is simple http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-or-qgis/148030#148030

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Turns out the PostGIS [ST_PointOnSurface](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_PointOnSurface.html) function is "good enough", and based on an explanation in this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated) it sounds like some of the approaches people have offered here and in the duplicate question. Somehow the function name/docs led me to believe that function placed the point on the polygon boundary.